# I dont know why my loop is not making the selection

Tags: php, codeigniter

`$carmakers` contains the name of cars make which is one of the value of maker in array.

What is troubling me is even though the `$carmakers` variable is not empty it doesnt  go to this condition?

```
    <?php
    if($val->title == $carmakers){ echo 'selected = "selected"' ; }
    ?>
```

My Full Code is:

```
    <?php foreach ($carmake as $key1 => $carmakers):?>            
               <select name="maker[]" class="car_make " >
                    <?php if (empty($carmakers)): ?> 
                       <option>Please Select Car Option</option>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($maker as $key => $val): ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $val->title; ?> "
                       <?php if($val->title == $carmakers){ echo 'selected = "selected"' ; }?>  >
                       <?php echo strtoupper($val->title); ?>
                       </option>                                                      
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
               </select>
   <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: what do you get if you use print_r($carmakers) ?

Comment: i get the results contained in that array

Comment: $carmake what is it? array of WHAT? Entities, entries, CActiveRecord, Doctrine2 ?

Comment: What is $maker in second foreach? show your full description of $carmake . (I wonder why question wasn't closed yet.)

Comment: $maker is another array dont you see when it is followed with foreach ..

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach loop seems to be wrong.. it should look like this...

```
foreach ($carmakers as $key => $carmake)
```

Yours looks like this...

```
foreach ($carmake as $key => $carmakers)
```

Comment: i am looking it in the same way you are looking at..i mean to say i get the value.when print_r($carmakers).